# Pandas shows up with a bunch of errers when running simple code

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I am trying to write a program that chooses a recipie for me to cook at random so i found a csv file to get the recipies from but when i tried running some code this happened.
I'm new to pandas so sorry if this is stupid

`

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


pd.read_csv('recipes.csv')
pd.isnull()
```

`
https://github.com/cweber/cookbook/blob/master/recipes.csv (this is the link to the csv file)

[image]

Comment: store you file in a variable `df=pd.read_csv('recipes.csv')`

Comment: @Mehmaam but the code fails at `pd.read_csv('recipes.csv')`, i.e., it can't parse the CSV.

Comment: issue in the csv file, i also cannot parse it

Comment: try `df=pd.read_csv('recipes.csv', index_col=None, header=0, engine='python')` after that i can do it